# Ubuntu 20.04 slows down after usage

Tags: performance, cpu

I have a DELL laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.
It's been a while that after some usage (e.g. firefox, some video-calls, etc.) it becomes slow. There are some processes which start to take higher percentage of cpu (even if they do not take the whole cpu). In this image there's the output of htop.[image: My processes]

I don't understand why those processes keep my cpu usage high.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: As you can see in the image, I have 32 GB of Ram. The computer slows down depending on what I do. Also youtube videos slow down my laptop. At the beginning (one month ago) it was much faster. I also tried to re-install Ubuntu but it didn't get better.

EDIT2: Some more command outputs from the command line[image: top output]
and
[image: Other command outputs]

EDIT3:

```
francesco@dell-latitude-inria:~/Desktop$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:165 memory:cb000000-cbffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

then

```
francesco@dell-latitude-inria:~/Desktop$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.12.0
       date: 02/24/2021
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 20
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: HMA82GS6JJR8N-VK
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 0
          serial: 2FA26C44
          slot: DIMM A
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: HMA82GS6JJR8N-VK
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 1
          serial: 2FA26909
          slot: DIMM B
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 29
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 2a
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 2b
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:cc320000-cc321fff memory:cc32b000-cc32bfff
```

then

```
francesco@dell-latitude-inria:~/Desktop$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 francesco francesco 4096 mai   19 11:47 .
drwx------ 3 francesco francesco 4096 mai   28 13:39 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 francesco francesco 4096 mai   19 11:47 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

then

```
francesco@dell-latitude-inria:~/Desktop$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 avril 23  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 mai   19 09:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mai   19 09:17 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 mai   19 09:17 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 mai   19 09:17 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

then

```
francesco@dell-latitude-inria:~/Desktop$ snap list
Name                 Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher         Notes
canonical-livepatch  9.6.2                       99     latest/stable    canonical✓        -
core                 16-2.50                     11081  latest/stable    canonical✓        core
core18               20210507                    2066   latest/stable    canonical✓        base
core20               20210429                    1026   latest/stable    canonical✓        base
gimp                 2.10.24                     372    latest/stable    snapcrafters      -
gnome-3-28-1804      3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓        -
gnome-3-34-1804      0+git.3556cb3               66     latest/stable/…  canonical✓        -
gtk-common-themes    0.1-52-gb92ac40             1515   latest/stable/…  canonical✓        -
snap-store           3.38.0-59-g494f078          518    latest/stable/…  canonical✓        -
snapd                2.50                        11841  latest/stable    canonical✓        snapd
telegram-desktop     2.7.4                       2637   latest/stable    telegram.desktop  -
```

EDIT 4:

When trying to open an application (firefox, or visual studio code) what happens is that they take a LOT of CPU at the beginning and then not anymore, but still the system is slow

```
top - 17:30:58 up 27 min,  1 user,  load average: 1,82, 3,20, 3,41
Tasks: 296 total,   6 running, 290 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 54,5 us,  8,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 37,3 id,  0,2 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,1 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  31930,6 total,  26496,8 free,   2301,1 used,   3132,8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.  28361,5 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                   
  10409 frances+  20   0 4475420 120928  61060 R 167,8   0,4   0:09.46 code                                                      
  10341 frances+  20   0   50,5g 255440 111076 R 159,3   0,8   0:15.14 code                                                      
  10382 frances+  20   0 4508992 139532  66160 R  57,0   0,4   0:03.10 code                                                      
  10394 frances+  20   0   36,4g 169484  93784 S  30,3   0,5   0:07.08 code                                                      
   1842 frances+  20   0 5270364 291192 105076 S  16,9   0,9   4:10.51 gnome-shell                                               
  10309 frances+  20   0  543340 125196  89264 R  14,3   0,4   0:01.81 code                                                      
  10279 frances+  20   0 4775044 144700 106712 S  14,0   0,4   0:01.71 code                                                      
   1683 frances+  20   0  869272  78712  43672 R  10,7   0,2   2:25.79 Xorg                                                      
   9860 frances+  20   0  968660  54596  41608 S   5,9   0,2   0:02.94 gnome-terminal-                                           
  10450 frances+  20   0   10896   5096   3460 S   5,9   0,0   0:00.18 bash                                                      
  10430 frances+  20   0 4475432  76348  60928 S   4,6   0,2   0:00.83 code                                                      
    768 root      20   0  273900   9404   8544 S   3,3   0,0   0:38.77 thermald                                                  
  10328 frances+  20   0  256532  77572  68320 S   3,3   0,2   0:00.16 code                                                      
   9300 frances+  20   0 3994300 430172 221396 S   1,6   1,3   2:10.01 firefox                                                   
   9877 frances+  20   0   12132   4200   3260 R   1,6   0,0   0:01.59 top                                                       
   9192 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   1,3   0,0   0:01.29 kworker/5:3-events                                        
   9598 frances+  20   0 2882896 254248 156000 S   1,3   0,8   1:19.61 Web Content                                               
   9510 frances+  20   0 2496384 140660  96472 S   0,7   0,4   0:13.56 WebExtensions
```

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Slowing down after several hours of, or otherwise heavy usage is most often related to having started to utilize the swap disk area; that always slows things down.

Comment: As you can see in the image, I have 32 GB of Ram. But I'm not talking about several hours, I'm talking about some minutes. It depends on what I do. Also youtube videos slow down my laptop. At the beginning (one month ago) it was much faster. I also tried to re-install Ubuntu but it didn't get better.

Comment: Oh, 32GB is plenty enough and is indeed barely used out; now I even see that your swap is not being used at all. My suggestion was silly then.

Comment: Is your HDD light blinking continuously?  (i.e., indicating that a lot of read/write is happening).  Only 10% of your memory is being used, none of your swap, and very little of each of your 8 threads.  Nothing you're showing us is indicating computer slowing down...  Did you update the files on Dropbox and it's busy pulling down the changes?  That or a "backup at start up" are two reasons I can think of why a computer slows down upon start up...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any HDD light (DELL Latitude 7400). You're right, only 10% of my memory, and even the processes do not use high percentages of CPU. But, normally, those first three processes take much less than these. The laptop slows down not at start up, but after I perform some particular actions, that usually involve videos, like youtube video reproduction, video-calls, even playing chess on chess websites on firefox.

Comment: Edit your question and show me (when the system is slow) `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `top` (not htop). Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thank you. I'll do it asap

Comment: @heynnema here it is. I edited the question content. The computer slowed down during a zoom call on firefox, and kept slow afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the data. I didn't see what I expected to see. That output was taken when the system was slow, yes? I'll have to ask a number of more questions to gather more data before I can make a recommendation. Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C video` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `snap list`.

Comment: Also, although it's a big job, I'll want to take a look at syslog. When the system is slow, do `cat /var/log/syslog` and paste that output at paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL. Tell me the approx time that the system got slow so that I can focus on that part of syslog.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem with 20.10 and Latitude 5480

Comment: Here are the info you requested to the original poster, in case it is useful: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qpFg8gkV8f/

Comment: @Leandro Please start a new question, and include all of the details. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema already figured it out my problem in my separate question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341064/cpu-usage-too-high-on-ubuntu-20-10#1341120). Check if your power supply is working correctly, perhaps you have the same problem I have.

Comment: @heynnema thank you for your help. Yes, that was taken when the system was slow, even if not that much slow. But it's still strange since a few months ago my laptop was never slow. The outputs of your last instructions have been posted (but the system was not slow at that time). I'll try to reproduce conditions to make my laptop slow and send you the syslog.

Comment: @heynnema https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rXYQDqfCKq/ starting at around 14.00 I noticed the system was slow trying to launch some simple python scripts.

Comment: @FdA Please take a look at my initial answer. What is **remarkable**? Do you have any custom themes installed?

Answer (score 1):

partial answer...

In reviewing /var/log/syslog around the suspected time of slowdown, I come away with these processes that need investigation...

- remarkable - **lots** of network errors
- livepatch - performing updates
- telegram - real time priority
- gnome-shell - window manager errors (do you have any themes installed?)

**Update #1:**

Reviewed 2nd syslog...

- **lots** of wireless disconnects/reconnects
- gnome-shell crash

**Update #2:**

- the `code` application is using a lot of CPU%

Comment: remarkable is something I just installed today, it's a desktop manager for a notepad. It has no original debian distribution, I was trying some open software online. Should not be an issue. Maybe I installed some extra-feature for the dark theme of gnome-shell. I do I remove it?

Ho do I investigate the other? And how do I lower priority for telegram? Thanks!

Furthermore, today Ubuntu experienced an internal error because of Geoclue.

Comment: I just disabled all extension I added with gnome-tweaks. Let's see how it goes

Comment: @FdA What version Remarkable? If there's no debian distribution, how did you install it? Have you created a Remarkable account at their web site? Do you have any themes installed?

Comment: @FdA You only added one gnome-shell extension, yes?

Comment: there are debian distributions, but not "official" ones https://remarkablewiki.com/tips/client. I have an account, yes. They should synchronize but they do not, while it performs well on the Android app. But this should not be an issue since I installed it today. My "slowness" problem is older.

Comment: @FdA Have you enabled Livepatch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124795/discussion-between-fda-and-heynnema).

Comment: I have some issues, again. Writing you in the chat @heynnema

Answer (score 1):

I have a Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 3 with Ubuntu 22.10 that had all the same symptoms listed above.  I went through all the different answers in the attempt to solve my problem.

The cause ended up being clogged dust filters.  Once I cleaned them everything was back to normal.

One of the things that threw me off was that `cat /proc/cpuinfo` was not showing throttled CPUs and the CPU temps were in the high 70s, which is hot but not critically so.

What finally made me clean the filters was that the whole laptop was very warm (it sits on my desk and I normally never touch it).  So if none of the other answers help you, check your laptop temp.