# CPU usage too high on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: firefox, performance, cpu, 20.10

It's been some days since everything got slowed down on my Dell Latitude 5480. I have 16GB RAM, rarely its usage goes beyond 40%, but applications that normally don't use that much CPU now they go up to 100%, especially videos. I tried switching from Firefox to Chromium, I disabled GPU acceleration on Firefox, to no avail. On those cases, top would show Firefox or Chromium as culprits, but in the Firefox tasks console there's nothing wrong, no tab is especially taking too much CPU in Firefox's opinion. I would like to stress that this wasn't happening at all some days ago.
Here is some information that @heynnema requested on a similar case ([Ubuntu 20.04 slows down after usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340825/ubuntu-20-04-slows-down-after-usage)): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qpFg8gkV8f/

```
$ top

top - 20:54:37 up 3 min,  1 user,  load average: 6,82, 3,20, 1,26
Tasks: 254 total,   3 running, 251 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 75,5 us, 23,5 sy,  0,0 ni,  1,0 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15871,7 total,  11662,1 free,   2618,7 used,   1590,9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  30518,0 total,  30518,0 free,      0,0 used.  12718,8 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                        
   2153 leandro   20   0 3692108 551256 171408 R 170,0   3,4   2:58.64 firefox                                                                        
   2701 leandro   20   0 2845060 376568 176988 R  75,0   2,3   0:44.78 Web Content                                                                    
   2432 leandro   20   0   26,9g 571352  98404 S  45,0   3,5   1:04.69 WebExtensions                                                                  
   2825 leandro   20   0  218560  58392  42652 S  20,0   0,4   0:01.66 RDD Process                                                                    
   2902 leandro   20   0   21524   4312   3512 R  20,0   0,0   0:00.08 top                                                                            
   2275 leandro   20   0 2711824 302536 103468 S  15,0   1,9   0:45.91 Web Content                                                                    
   1655 leandro   20   0  862908  73856  49624 S  10,0   0,5   0:14.60 Xorg                                                                           
   1856 leandro   20   0 4007508 267416 103672 S  10,0   1,6   0:35.87 gnome-shell                                                                    
   2504 leandro   20   0 2486004 157748 100972 S  10,0   1,0   0:06.86 Web Content                                                                    
   2213 leandro   20   0 2523948 177836 108792 S   5,0   1,1   0:13.12 Web Content                                                                    
   2331 leandro   20   0  835556  62888  40308 S   5,0   0,4   0:04.37 terminator                                                                     
      1 root      20   0  169312  12420   8652 S   0,0   0,1   0:03.93 systemd                                                                        
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                       
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                         
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                     
      5 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0-events                                                             
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                           
      7 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:1-events                                                             
      8 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.14 kworker/u8:0-ext4-rsv-conversion                                               
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                   
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd/0                                                                    
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.65 rcu_sched                                                                      
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                    
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                  
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                        
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                        
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                  
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.21 migration/1                                                                    
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.08 ksoftirqd/1                                                                    
     19 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 kworker/1:0-events                                                             
     20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd                                                           
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2       

$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2,4Gi        11Gi       206Mi       1,5Gi        12Gi
Swap:          29Gi          0B        29Gi


$ sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt --interval 15
turbostat version 20.03.20 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 0x16 CPUID levels; 0x80000008 xlevels; family:model:stepping 0x6:8e:9 (6:142:9)
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR SMX EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM HT TM
CPUID(6): APERF, TURBO, DTS, PTM, HWP, HWPnotify, HWPwindow, HWPepp, No-HWPpkg, EPB
cpu2: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x00850089 (TCC EIST MWAIT PREFETCH TURBO)
CPUID(7): SGX
cpu2: MSR_IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000005 (Locked )
CPUID(0x15): eax_crystal: 2 ebx_tsc: 226 ecx_crystal_hz: 0
TSC: 2712 MHz (24000000 Hz * 226 / 2 / 1000000)
CPUID(0x16): base_mhz: 2700 max_mhz: 3500 bus_mhz: 100
cpu2: MSR_MISC_PWR_MGMT: 0x00401cc0 (ENable-EIST_Coordination DISable-EPB DISable-OOB)
RAPL: 17476 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 15 Watts
cpu2: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0x804043df1011b00
4 * 100.0 = 400.0 MHz max efficiency frequency
27 * 100.0 = 2700.0 MHz base frequency
cpu2: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x0024005d (C1E auto-promotion: DISabled)
cpu2: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x23232323
35 * 100.0 = 3500.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
35 * 100.0 = 3500.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
35 * 100.0 = 3500.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
35 * 100.0 = 3500.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
cpu2: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_NOMINAL: 0x0000001a (base_ratio=26)
cpu2: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_1: 0x0008003c (PKG_MIN_PWR_LVL1=0 PKG_MAX_PWR_LVL1=0 LVL1_RATIO=8 PKG_TDP_LVL1=60)
cpu2: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_2: 0x001b00c8 (PKG_MIN_PWR_LVL2=0 PKG_MAX_PWR_LVL2=0 LVL2_RATIO=27 PKG_TDP_LVL2=200)
cpu2: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_CONTROL: 0x00000000 ( lock=0)
cpu2: MSR_TURBO_ACTIVATION_RATIO: 0x00000017 (MAX_NON_TURBO_RATIO=23 lock=0)
cpu2: MSR_PKG_CST_CONFIG_CONTROL: 0x1e008008 (UNdemote-C3, UNdemote-C1, demote-C3, demote-C1, locked, pkg-cstate-limit=8 (unlimited))
cpu2: cpufreq driver: intel_pstate
cpu2: cpufreq governor: powersave
cpufreq intel_pstate no_turbo: 0
cpu2: MSR_MISC_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000000 (L2-Prefetch L2-Prefetch-pair L1-Prefetch L1-IP-Prefetch)
cpu0: MSR_PM_ENABLE: 0x00000001 (HWP)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_CAPABILITIES: 0x01081a23 (high 35 guar 26 eff 8 low 1)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_REQUEST: 0x80002304 (min 4 max 35 des 0 epp 0x80 window 0x0 pkg 0x0)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_INTERRUPT: 0x00000000 (Dis_Guaranteed_Perf_Change, Dis_Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_STATUS: 0x00000000 (No-Guaranteed_Perf_Change, No-Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: 0x00000006 (balanced)
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x000a0e03 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000061 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x00000078 (15 W TDP, RAPL 0 - 0 W, 0.000000 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x4280c800dd8078 (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (15.000000 Watts, 28.000000 sec, clamp ENabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: ENabled (25.000000 Watts, 0.002441* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_DRAM_POWER_LIMIT: 0x5400de00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: DRAM Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POLICY: 0
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: Cores Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POLICY: 0
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: GFX Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x02640000 (100 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x883a0008 (42 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_INTERRUPT: 0x00000003 (100 C, 100 C)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC3_IRTL: 0x0000884e (valid, 79872 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC6_IRTL: 0x00008876 (valid, 120832 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC7_IRTL: 0x00008894 (valid, 151552 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC8_IRTL: 0x000088fa (valid, 256000 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC9_IRTL: 0x0000894c (valid, 339968 ns)
cpu2: MSR_PKGC10_IRTL: 0x00008bf2 (valid, 1034240 ns)
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
81.37   628 120145  42  1.86    0.08    0.53
78.13   615 124712  42  1.77    0.07    0.51
49.01   637 80666   41  1.45    0.04    0.36

$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.17.1

$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda3                               partition   31250428    0   -2

$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=174e804f-da04-4503-81f9-999b012324a1 none            swap    sw              0       0

$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Comment: Just as a test, try disabling thermald. There have been reports of [the backported thermald](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thermald/+bug/1913186) to include the adaptive engine breaking some systems, although not in this same way. (I asked one sufferer to enter a new bug report, but it appears they didn't). What is your CPU frequency during "high usage"?

Comment: Remove telegram-deskop [See here](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/6738) and try again

Comment: @kanehekili: I have been using Telegram Desktop for too long now to blame it. But I will give it a try.

Comment: @DougSmythies: CPU frequency is about 600-610 Mhz when in high CPU usage. Removing thermald made no difference.

Comment: I briefly reviewed your syslog. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable the disable-gestures and system-monitor gnome-shell extensions, then restart gnome-shell or reboot. Also, when the system is slow, edit your question and show me `free -h` and `top`.

Comment: We need to determine why your CPU frequency is being forced low.

Comment: @heynnema: I edited and added the requested information.

Comment: @DougSmythies: whatever test you want me to make, I willingly do.

Comment: I pretty much always ask for the same thing: `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt --interval 15` . You already mentioned the CPU frequency is not increasing as it normally would. Dell sometimes forces such if it thinks you are not using a Dell power supply or other reasons.

Comment: @DougSmythies: added that info to the main post as well. Given what you said, I should add that the battery stopped working so it's only powered with the main power supply. I even removed the battery because I suspected it could tamper the performance, but it didn't change anything. This began to happen more or less when the battery stopped working.

Comment: 30G swap! That's nuts. Do you hibernate? Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `swapon -s` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Firefox usage is very high... if you quit it... relaunch it with no open/used tabs... what's the usage? Did you disable the two gnome-shell extensions that I called out?

Comment: @heynnema: I added the information you requested.

Comment: @heynnema: oh, and I did disable the extensions.

Comment: I updated my answer, as you're using /dev/sda3 as a swap partition, and I'm converting you to a 4G /swapfile. You should only do this if you're NOT hibernating.

Comment: What about my Firefox question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Power Manager**

Due to battery/power issues...

With the computer shut down, hold down the POWER key for ~30 seconds. This will reset the Power Manager. See if there's any operational improvement.

**BIOS**

Dell Latitude 5480

You have BIOS version 1.17.1, dated 1/7/2020. There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.19.2, dated 5/4/2021, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-14-5480-laptop/drivers).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**SWAP**

30G swap is nuts. Assuming that you're using a /swapfile, and not a disk partition, and not hibernating, we'll reduce the /swapfile to 4G.

---

**Update**: You're using /dev/sda3 as a swap partition. We can still create a 4G /swapfile using the procedure below, and then use `gparted` to delete /dev/sda3. Only do this if you are NOT hibernating. Also comment out the following line in /etc/fstab...

```
UUID=174e804f-da04-4503-81f9-999b012324a1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

---

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**vm.swappiness**

Your vm.swappiness currently is set at the default of 60.

edits forthcoming...

**gnome-shell**

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable the `disable-gestures` and `system-monitor` gnome-shell extensions, then restart gnome-shell or reboot. See if things improve.

**Firefox**

edits forthcoming...

Comment: Well, you and @DougSmythies got it right. After power manager reset, there's a warning on boot: "Alert: The AC power adapter wattage and type cannot be determined. The battery may no charge. The system will adjust the performance to match the power available". This explains why the battery stopped working and why the CPU frequency got this low. I suppose I will have to get a new power supply. Thank you very much to both of you for figuring it out!

Comment: As for the BIOS update, it's only available for Windows.

Comment: @Leandro It sounds like your laptop power brick, or your desktop power supply, need to be replaced. BIOS updates are usually Windows .exe files. Some BIOS allow updating from within the BIOS itself. If you don't have a dual-boot system with Windows, you can try FreeDOS (https://www.freedos.org).

Comment: @Leandro : In the mean time, you could try disabling HWP, `intel_pstate=no_hwp` on grub command line, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`. The algorithm is different for HWP disabled, and if I recall correctly, is less effected by clock modulation, which I think is what Dell uses. You still will not get to full CPU frequency, but might get much higher, not sure.

Comment: @DougSmythies: thank you again, will try that!

Comment: @DougSmythies: well, it got to 900Mhz, at least something improved, you're great.

Comment: @Leandro : O.K. now set it to use the performance governor and you will have highest possible (might still be only 900 MHz), until you get a new power supply. `echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. You could also try to overwrite the clock modulation register, but that gets complicated.

Comment: @Leandro Did you fix your swap?

Comment: @DougSmythies: thank you, it varies a lot, sometimes it shows almost 3Ghz!

Comment: @heynnema: yes! I have it in 4GB now, thank you.