# Getting Stuck on Low Clock Frequencies

Tags: 20.04, power-management, intel, performance, cpufreq

I have been using the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for the past three months after dualbooting it with Windows 10, and recently it has started showing some problems.
I usually use my laptop(Lenovo Ideapad C340) for running Deep Learning Programs(no CUDA) and for the past few days, when I run my python DL program, sometimes the Clock frequency gets stuck to 0.40 GHz and the whole system begins to lag.
Similar thing happens whenever I open a browser(firefox or chrome).
This behaviour is quite random and has only started occuring in the past couple of days. I tried updating Ubuntu, but the problem persists. I also tried using the CPU Power Manager(Gnome-Shell Extension for the intel-pstate driver) but this doesn't work as well.
(Note: The behaviour looks quite random, which is to say, sometimes the system runs fine but sometimes this issue arises)(Note: CPU is Intel Core i5 8th gen)

Comment: Ultimately we need to determine why your system decided to throttle down and the method it used to do so, and why it sticks there. It sounds like clock modulation. Dell computers force clock modulation when they do not detect a proper Dell power adapter, but I don't know about Lenovo. Disable HWP and/or use the performance CPU frequency scaling governor to partially overcome the issue. See my comments on both question and answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341064/cpu-usage-too-high-on-ubuntu-20-10).

Comment: With the computer shut down, hold down the POWER key for ~30 seconds. This will reset the Power Manager. See if there's any operational improvement.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to run this bash script to see if this changes anything:**

*Make a file named anything you like and enter in this code:*

```
#!/bin/bash
#Getting and setting variables

echo Getting info....

CPUMIN=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq)
CPUMAX=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq)
CPUMAXGHZ=$(echo "scale=1; $CPUMAX / 1000000" | bc)
CPUMINGHZ=$(echo "scale=1; $CPUMIN / 1000000" | bc)

#Display min and max CPU frequency in MHz
echo CPU min frequency: $CPUMIN" MHz" / $CPUMINGHZ" GHz"
echo CPU max frequency: $CPUMAX" MHz" / $CPUMAXGHZ" GHz"

#Setting CPU governor
echo Setting governor to performance
sudo cpufreq-set -r -g performance
echo Set governor to performance

#Setting to max frequency
echo Setting CPU frequency to be $CPUMAX" MHz" / $CPUMAXGHZ" GHz"
sudo cpufreq-set -r -f $CPUMAXGHZ"GHz"
echo Set CPU frequency to $CPUMAXGHZ"GHz"

done
```

**To execute the following script run:**

```
sudo sh yourfilename.sh
```

Replace [yourfilename] with the file name that you created.

**To check the CPU frequency live run:**

```
watch -n 0.1 grep \"cpu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, what did it was resetting the CMOS by opening the computer and unplugging the CMOS button battery (as well as the main battery). I'm running an i9-13900H, on a Dell Precision 3581